# knockoutjs submit with ko.utils.postJson issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I followed the http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/ article to submit data using ko.utils.postJson and navigate to a different view from the controller

I used `ko.utils.postJson(location.href, {model: ko.toJson(viewModel)});` to submit the data but the model submitted to the server has empty properties.

`ko.utils.postJson(location.href, {model: viewModel});` failed too.

The client viewModel has additional properties than the server model but I believe if it works with $ajax post method, it should work with KO post

It worked if I pass the model as under

```
ko.utils.postJson(location.href, 
    {model: {P1:this.p1(), P2:this.p2(), P3: this.p3()}});
```

Do I have to map each property before submission? Its also really confusing when to use () for viewModel properties

**Server Code**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SearchProperty([FromJson]MyModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                return View("XYZ", model);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knockout provides a utility function that will turn an object containing observables into a plain JavaScript object.  The utility function is `ko.toJS`.  So, if you did:

```
   { model: ko.toJS(viewModel) }
```

Then, it would handle unwrapping all of your observables.

Additionally, there is another function `ko.toJSON` that will do a `ko.toJS` and then do `JSON.stringify` on the result.  This is useful when you really need JSON instead of a JavaScript object.